# Разделить row на 3 части

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть следующая конструкция:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <!-- левая колонка с картинкой -->
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <!-- img class="imgd" src="img/Lady in Red.jpg" / -->
    <img src="//picsum.photos/200/301" alt="picsum.photos" title="placeholder picsum.photos">
  </div>
  <!-- правая колонка с текстом и кнопкой -->
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="wrapper cursor">
      <div class="caption post-content cursor">
        <p class="aria">Text1</p>
        <p class="fontd">Text2</p>
        <button class="buttonx">Посмотреть продукт</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Он расширяется по горизонтали полностью. Нужно разделить на 3 части, чтобы поместилось горизонтально 3 таких блока. Чтобы адаптивны были.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- левая колонка с картинкой -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="imgd" src="img/Lady in Red.jpg" />
      </div>
      <!-- правая колонка с текстом и кнопкой -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="wrapper cursor">
          <div class="caption post-content cursor">
            <p class="aria">Text1</p>
            <p class="fontd">Text2</p>
            <button class="buttonx">Посмотреть продукт</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- левая колонка с картинкой -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="imgd" src="img/Lady in Red.jpg" />
      </div>
      <!-- правая колонка с текстом и кнопкой -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="wrapper cursor">
          <div class="caption post-content cursor">
            <p class="aria">Text1</p>
            <p class="fontd">Text2</p>
            <button class="buttonx">Посмотреть продукт</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- левая колонка с картинкой -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="imgd" src="img/Lady in Red.jpg" />
      </div>
      <!-- правая колонка с текстом и кнопкой -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="wrapper cursor">
          <div class="caption post-content cursor">
            <p class="aria">Text1</p>
            <p class="fontd">Text2</p>
            <button class="buttonx">Посмотреть продукт</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```